# Azure CosmosDB I cannot get more than 1500 RUs

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-cosmosdb

I have an application that requires large RUs, but for some reason I cannot get the client app to handle more than 1000-1500 RUs, although the collection is set to 10000 RUs. Obviously I can add more clients, but I need one client to give me at least 10000 RUs then scale that. 
My requests are simple

```
    var query = connection.CreateDocumentQuery<DocumentDBProfile>(
    CollectionUri, //cached
    "SELECT * FROM Col1 WHERE Col1.key = '" + partitionKey + "' AND Col1.id ='" + id + "'",
    new FeedOptions
    {
        MaxItemCount = -1,
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10000000,
        MaxBufferedItemCount = 1000,
    }).AsDocumentQuery();
    var dataset = await query.ExecuteNextAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The query above is hitting 150,000 partitions, each is within own task (awaiting all at the end) and the client is initialized with TCP and direct mode:

```
                            var policy = new ConnectionPolicy
                            {
                                EnableEndpointDiscovery = false,
                                ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
                                ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp,
                            };
```

The CPU on the client appears to max out, mostly to service the call query.ExecuteNextAsync()

Am I doing anything wrong? Any optimization tips? Is there a lower level API I can use? Is there a way to pre-parse queries or make Json parsing more optimal?

**UPDATE**
I was able to get up to 3000-4000 RU on one client by lowering the number of concurrent requests, and stripping down my deserialized class to one with a single property (id), but I am still 10% of the limit of 50,000 RUs mentioned in the performance guidelines.
Not sure what else I could do. Is there any security checks or overhead I can disable in the .Net SDK?

**UPDATE2**
All our tests are run on Azure in the same region D11_V2. Running multiple clients scales well, so we are client bound not server bound.
Still not able to achieve 10% of the performance outlined in the [CosmosDB performance guideline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/performance-tips)

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the question: are you being throttled? If not, increasing RU won't help.

Comment: Hi David, No I am not being throttled, I am trying to get my client handle more RUs, this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/performance-tips says 50,000 is the point we should scale the client, but I am not getting even 10% of that

Comment: I basically need a more efficient query.ExecuteNextAsync

Comment: Are you running your application in debug mode, or release?

Comment: I tried both release and debug, no noticeable difference. Is there a release and debug versions of the SDK?

Comment: Have you tried running the test client on the same azure region as your documentDB? Maybe the latency playes some tricks on your network card? I've seen it happen that a network card was strangling CPU. I would suggest trying a different client server (preferably in azure) and scaling up until it is no longer CPU-limited.

Comment: Thanks Imre, yes, the actual tests we ran on Azure VM (D11_V2 ) same region. Running multiple VMs scales well, so it is definitely client side problem. I just don't see how we could get the 50000 RU/s per client they talk about in the documentation. Have you measured the highest RU/s you can get on one client?

Answer (score 3):

By default the SDK will use a [retry policy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.azure.documents.client.connectionpolicy.retryoptions.aspx#P:Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.ConnectionPolicy.RetryOptions) to mask throttling errors. Have you looked at the RU metrics available on Azure portal to confirm if you are being throttled or not? For more details on this, see tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/monitor-accounts).

Not sure why the REST API would perform better than the .NET SDK. Can you give some more details on the operation you used here?

The example query you provided is querying a single document with a known partitionkey and id per request. For this kind of point-read operation, it would be better to use `DocumentClient.ReadDocumentAsnyc`, as it should be cheaper than a query.

Comment: Hi Oliver, the reasons for query instead of ReadDocumentAsnyc is due to a bug with ReadDocumentAsnyc making it very slow when the documents are not present (it throws exceptions)

Comment: I have removed the REST API comment, I somehow cannot reproduce that result anymore. But in any case, my queries are CPU bound on the client which is causing the slowdown. I am not getting throttled at all by the server, I am getting a maximum RUs of 4000, and average around 2000.

Comment: Just to check, the bug you are referring to is this [one](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/219). Can you share an example of the exception you were seeing as well as full code sample repro (both for ReadDoucmentAsync and CreateDocumentQuery).

Comment: Hi Oliver, yes the exception is due to 404, same one you refer to in your link. I don't see exceptions with CreateDocumentQuery. Yes I can share the code sample but rather large to share here, is there a different way I can share with you?

Comment: Hi Oliver, do you know if the 50,000 RU/s per 1 client is realistic? Is even 10,000 realistic? Have you been able to get such performance from 1 or 2 core VM on Azure?

Comment: Hi @Oliver, is there a contact person we can reach at MS regarding CosmosDB? We are really hitting a wall here

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your sole purpose has become to disprove the documentation of Microsoft. Don't overrate this "50.000 RU/S" value for how you should scale your clients.

I don't think you can get a faster & lower level API than using .NET SDK with TCP & direct mode. The critical part is to use the TCP protocol (which you are). Only Java SDK also has direct mode, i doubt its faster. Maybe .NET Core...

How can your requirement be to "have large RU/s"? That is equivalent to "the application should require us to pay X$ for CosmosDB every month". The requirement should rather be "needs to complete X queries per second" or something like this. You then go on from there. See also the [request unit calculator](https://www.documentdb.com/capacityplanner#).

A request unit is the cost of your transaction. It depends on how large your documents are, how your collection is configured and on **what your are doing**. Inserting documents is usually much more expensive than retrieving data. Retrieving data across partitions within one query is more expensive than touching only a single one. A rule of thumb is that writing data is about 5 times more expensive than reading it.
I suggest you read the [documentation about request units](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/request-units).

The problem with the performance tip of Microsoft is that they don't mention anything about which request should incur those RU/s. I would not expect it to mean: "The most basic request possible will not max out the CPU on the client system if you are still below 50.000 RU/s". Inserting data will get you to those numbers much more easily. I did a very quick test on my *local* machine, and got the [official benchmarking sample](http://Performance%20and%20scale%20testing%20with%20Azure%20Cosmos%20DB) up to about 7-8k RU/s using TCP+direct. I did not do anything apart from downloading the code and running it from Visual Studio. So my guess would be that the tips are also about inserting, since the performance testing examples are as well. The example achieves 100.000RU/s incidentally.

There are some good samples from Azure about "[Benchmarking](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/tree/master/samples/documentdb-benchmark)" and "[Request Units](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/tree/master/samples/request-units)". They should also be good sources for further experiments.

**Only one actual tip on how to improve your query:** Maybe ditch deserialization to your class, using `CreateDocumentQuery(..)` or `CreateDocumentQuery<dynamic>`. Could help your CPU. My first guess would be that your CPU is doing a bunch of that.

Hope this helps in any way.

Comment: Hi Alex, NO the purpose is not disproving the documentation. We have a requirement to run several hundreds of reads per second (possibly millions), and as it stands this means we have to run a massive number of clients (hundreds of them) to read our database. Before we go and change our whole infrastructure, we need to test if CosmosDB can provide such performance. The server appears to work, the SDK not so much. Our system already works with other databases, and gives us such performance without running hundreds of clients. It is strange that you have to run so many clients for DB reads!

Comment: Yes, exactly, the statement by MS is vague (what operations? what client specs?), hence I am trying to ask here, are we doing something wrong? Are there any other optimization steps we need to take? You can't build a DB engine and not have actual performance white papers?! Also thanks for the tip, I already tried moving the CreateDocumentQuery and then start timing after all the queries are created, not much difference

Comment: BTW having 7-8K RU/s in inserts means you are doing 1-2K requests per second on the client, which puts it roughly near what we see.

Comment: I'm not saying you should create the Queries earlier, I'm saying you should write them differently (without your target type). Deserialization happens in ExecuteNextAsync, when the actual data is retrieved. `.CreateDocumentQuery<DocumentDBProfile>` vs `.CreateDocumentQuery<dynamic>`

Comment: So you are saying you are not getting enough queries through per second? This would be a more accurate question IMO. You should not focus on the RU/s. Those 7k were done on a local machine btw, doing inserts. So not on Azure VM.

Comment: Microsoft does not use queries per second, they only use RU/s for measurement. Also queries per second is not exactly the same thing, I was able to get 4K RU/s by combining multiple reads into one query. If we are to query one document at a time, the RU/s is a lot lower, more like 1K.

Comment: Re:serialization, I already ruled out the serialization by adding my own custom serializer, didn't help. Why would CreateDocumentQuery<dynamic> be any different, doesn't it also do json de-serialization?

Comment: Just tested dynamic, there is no noticeable difference